# How to show missing data on CrystalReport Bar-Chart (show bar where value = 0 or null)

Tags: crystal-reports, bar-chart, missing-data, timeline

I created a **Bar Chart** in *Crystal Report* to show observed data on a time-line.

The data-source has only points for some time-values (axis labels), for example:

- 08:00
- 09:00
- 15:00

But on the graph I want to show all time-labels including the missing data (even if there were no points observed in the data):

[image]

Now it looks like this (missing some of the time labels):

[image]

**Please help me Show all time value on my bar chart graph**

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please _embed images_ by prefixing links with an exclamation-mark like `![image descirption](http://link.to/image)`

Comment: How does your dataset look like? Can you please post it as CSV, screenshot! Maybe the SQL query (if this is your datasource) may also help to find a solution.